# Issue with navigating a form using a combo box (MS Access)

Tags: ms-access

I have a combo box at the top of my form that is used to navigate the form. So if the user wants to go to record "ABC" they just find it in the combo box, click it, and it will take them there. My problem is that some of records have identical fields (there might be two "ABC" records) and even if I select the second "ABC" record, it will automatically take me to the first one. Any way to fix this? I know the easy way would be to not have duplicates, but the nature of this program requires it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Include the **Primary Key** column of the table in the combobox as invisible column (width = 0).

Then base your navigation on this column: `Me.myCombobox.Column(1)` for the second column.

If you have trouble implementing this, add your current navigation code to your question.